# Full Engine or Not: C++ Programmer Trying to get into Game Development

Tags: unity, opengl

I'm a fairly experienced programmer, and I want to try out doing some game development. However, I am unsure of whether or not to use a full engine like Unity or just start with something like OpenGL. How much flexibility/extensibility do you use going with Unity. I know it can be used with minimal coding, but if you can write your own code, will it constrain you later down the line? For my first project I want to just build a simple tile based rpg and build it up to something larger. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: If you want to build an engine, learn OpenGL and the like. If you want to jump straight into making a game, use an existing engine. Unity lets you use C#. Unreal Engine 4 lets you use C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a couple of coding related restrictions:

1. Unity is not (very) mulit-threaded.
2. You don't get direct access to the app's starting point or it's core rendering loop.
3. You can't call core windows or other OS specific libraries easily (because it's cross platform).

Other than that, you have almost the entire scope of .net 3.5 (C# and a version of javascript only.. and boo, but no one uses that) to work in.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I think I am going to go with Unity.